# Display Authors in a grid loop

Tags: loop, author, responsive, author-template, list-authors

I currently have the following php code which gives me a list of all the current WordPress authors, including their name and avatar.

```
<?php
    printf('<h1>%s</h1>', the_title());
    foreach($users as $user)
    {
        ?>
        <div class="author">
            <div class="authorAvatar">
                <?php echo get_avatar( $user->user_email, '128' ); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="authorInfo">
                <h2 class="authorName"><?php echo $user->display_name; ?></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
 ?>
```

I'm looking for a way to put this information in a 3 column grid that is setup like the following.

```
<div class="section group">
 <div class="col span_1_of_3">
  This is column 1
 </div>
 <div class="col span_1_of_3">
  This is column 2
 </div>
 <div class="col span_1_of_3">
  This is column 3
 </div>
</div>
```

The problem I'm facing is how to properly fill out the `col span_1_of_3` with each author that the php code generates. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely over thinking it

```
<div class="section group">
<?php
    printf('<h1>%s</h1>', the_title());

    foreach($users as $user)
    {
        ?>
        <div class="author">
            <div class="col span_1_of_3">
                <div class="authorAvatar">
                    <?php echo get_avatar( $user->user_email, '128' ); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="authorInfo">
                    <h2 class="authorName"><?php echo $user->display_name; ?></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
 ?>    
 </div>
```

Comment: Is this the answer? Or meant to be an edit to your question?